# How to display the data coming from backent on template(app.component.html)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-fullstack

[image: 1]

I am new to Angular . This is how my data(response) is coming from backend(see in the console in the picture attached). I want to somehow iterate this data in template and show to user. How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

[image: 2]

This image includes how i am getting data from backend.

[image: 3]

This image show my Jobs interface

Answer (score 0):

Use ngFor in your html file, you can put any html in this and it will loop over your array.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of loadedJobs"> 
  {{item.companyName}}
</div>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but nothing displays in the browser

Comment: in your case I believe it would be "let item of loadedJobs". are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No console errors

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let job of jobsloaded">
  {{job.companyName}}
</div>

Comment: Should be loadedJobs instead of jobsloaded right?

Comment: I solved it problem by just returning the list of my jobs from backend istead of with status code etc. and it worked (i just sent the request and subscribed it)